# finding the first value of one matrix after satisfying condition of another matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, conditional-statements

Please help me solve this problem...

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]  
b = [12 4 13 7 5 7 8 10 3 12]  
c = [4 5 3 2 6 7 5 3 4 5]
```

I have to find the first value on `a`, if the value on `b` is less than 10 for more than 3 consecutive places and index for the starting of satisfying the condition. Also the value of `c` after finding the value of `b` for same index.

Ans should be index for `b=4`, index for `a=4` and `value for a  =4` and `c=2`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may use [**`strfind`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) as one approach -

```
str1 = num2str(b <10,'%1d') %%// String of binary numbers
indx = strfind(['0' str1],'0111') %%// Indices where the condition is met
ind = indx(1) %%// Choose the first occurance
a_out = a(ind) %%// Index into a
c_out = c(ind) %%// Index into c
```

Output -

```
ind =
     4

a_out =
     4

c_out =
     2
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if b starts with 3 values less than 10.

Comment: @carlosdc Good find that one, fixed!

Comment: nice, it is fixed +1.

Comment: but I got a large data in excel where it is difficult to find the indices where condition is matched...please give some general code which may apply for all cases....the value of a b and c are just for example...thank you guys for help

Comment: @user3551734 This is a general code. Have you tried this with your large data?

Comment: yes I did that i got some error like this   ??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: How are you getting the data from excel? First make sure you are able to do so and put into vectors `a` `b` and `c`.

Comment: i m getting data in column...like   a=data(:,8)   b=data(:,9)...do i have to change it in rows.

Comment: @user3551734 Yes do that. `a`, `b` and `c` in the question and this answer assumes row vectors, whereas `data(:,8)` and `data(:,9)` would get column vectors.

Comment: ok....i transpose it.... and got error like this   ??? Attempted to access indx(1); index out of bounds because numel(indx)=0....what does it means

Comment: Try this - `a = data(:,8)'` and `b = data(:,9)'`. I am not sure how you are getting `c` though.

Comment: yep i did a=a'...its same thing...i m getting c in similar way...i haven't tried for this data i have given..but i am trying with my excel file.....hectic!!!!!i tried for loop...but it didn't worked out well

Comment: Tell me the output of `whos data`? So I am assuming `a` is the 8th column from `data`, `b` is the 9th one, isn't that right? What about `c`?

Comment: c from 10... and rows are 187...i have to find the first value of 'b' where the value of a is less than 1000000 for more than 10 consecutive times...and have to show the relation between b and c for the same time period by finding the corresponding value of c .....its just an experimental data over a long period of time

Comment: Let me ask you one more time, did you try this - `a = data(:,8)'`? Were you able to get `a` as a row vector with it?

Answer (score 0):

To find a given *number* of consecutive values lower than a *threshold*, you can apply [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) to a vector of `0`-`1` values resulting from the comparison:

```
threshold = 10; %// values "should" be smaller than this
number = 4; %// at least 4 consecutive occurrences

ind = find(conv(double(b<threshold), ones(1,number), 'valid')==number, 1);
%// double(b<threshold) gives 0-1.
%// conv(...)==... gives 1 when the sought number of consecutive 1's is reached
%// find(... ,1)  gives the first index where that happens
a_out = a(ind);
c_out = c(ind);
```